# Центр тяжести полигона

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Как по заданным вершинам многоугольника найти его центр тяжести?

В общем случае многоугольник может быть невыпуклым. Считать, что масса равномерно распределена по области, ограниченной многоугольником.

Comment: А что вы сами сделали для решения задачи? Судя по вопросу вы даже не пытались искать готовые решения.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов пытался

Comment: Серьезно? Гугл по вашей постановке задачи сразу готовые формулы выдает. Но гуглить - это ж не VK ломать...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов ссылки в студию

Comment: @vzlomvk, э нет, это не так работает :-) сначала вы показываете, что пытались делать, потом ваши попытки поправляют

Comment: @Grundy мне хотябы алгоритм нужен чтобы писать

Comment: @vzlomvk нет ни малейшего резона помогать человеку, который даже не хочет гуглить. Ваше дальнейшее пребывание на ресурсе будет состоять из таких же вопросов, где вы не будете ничего делать сами.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов значит не нашел а ничанаеш фигню писать

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов если это первые ссылки в гугле то че так сложно скинуть?

Comment: @vzlomvk я уже обосновал свою позицию: вам сложно гуглить и я специально (!) не буду давать вам ссылки, чтобы от вас таких вопросов тут больше не было.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов мда, я ж сказал что гуглил и ничего нет ты говориш что есть так покажи если не вреш

Comment: @Grundy и, где там нужный мне алгоритм?

Comment: Удалять, тут ничего не исправишь...

Comment: Не знаем как решить - удаляем посоны

Comment: @vzlomvk, но вы же даже не попытались. хоть что-то сделать. Даже по ссылке не перешли.

Comment: @Grundy ты издеваешся? я перешел и написал что там нет нужного мне алгоритма

Comment: а какой вам нужен алгоритм? по первой же ссылке идет алгоритм подсчета. если вам нужен какой-то другой алгоритм - укажите это в вопросе. По второй ссылке даже готовое решение на c++

Comment: @Grundy если вы сейчас дадите прямую ссылку на готовое решение на c++ я с позором покину сайт и не буду больше задавать вопросов

Comment: @vzlomvk, http://algolist.manual.ru/maths/geom/polygon/center_mass.php

Comment: и перед уходом, вопрос не забудьте удалить

Answer (score 1):

Написать следующие функции:

- вычисление веса треугольника по вершинам,
- ЦТ треугольника по вершинам,
- для определения принадлежности точки многоугольнику (это есть на СО),
- для определения веса и ЦТ двух фигур с известными ЦТ и весами.

Comment: т.к. "Считать, что масса равномерно распределена по области, ограниченной многоугольником.", то вес не нужен + зачем 3 функция?

Comment: 3-я функция, потому что будет выпуклый многоугольник и треугольники с отрицательным весом.

Comment: зачем мне писать не нужные дял моей задачи функции? давайте скину любые другие которые у меня уже написаны

Comment: если вы считаете что все 4 функции нужны, то объясните в чем состоит ваш алгоритм (в условии задачи не сказано, что нам дан вес)

Comment: вес не дан по условию, какой еще отрицательный вес

Comment: @vzlomvk: Очевидно, что от точного веса положение ЦТ не зависит, так что можно принять вес всей фигуры равным, например, 1. Но чтобы рассчитывать ЦТ целого по ЦТ частей, вам нужны их веса.

Comment: @VladD если мы принимаем вес за 1, то откуда появяться другие весы, они все будут отношениями координат относительно 1

Comment: @VladD вообще даже если бы нам был дан вес мы бы просто могли его умножать на отношение т.е. даже в этом случае не нужна функция с параметров вес

Comment: + провести разбиение невыпуклого треугольника на выпуклые так чтобы ещё и вес знать я хз как и возможно ли вообще

Comment: Замените вес площадью. Разницы нет.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov не повторяйте предыдущих коментаторов они тоже знают как решить но не покажут

Comment: Я не отличаюсь от предыдущих комментаторов в том, что работать за Вас не буду. Надеюсь, Вы понимаете разницу между советом и работой?

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov да но я не просил скинуть мне программу мне нужен алгоритм каким образом ее найти а напишу я сам

Comment: @vzlomvk: Алгоритм же описан в ответе. (1) Разбиваете многоугольник на треугольники. (Это нетривиально в случае невыпуклого многоугольника, и стоит отдельного вопроса.) (2) находите массы всех этих треугольников и положения ЦТ. (3) Заменяете каждый треугольник на его ЦТ и массу, равную массе треугольника. (4) Находите ЦТ конечной системы точек с весами.

Comment: @VladD и как мне найти массы этих треугольников если никакие массы  нам не дан?

Comment: @vzlomvk: Например, примите плотность материала за единицу (от этого положение ЦТ не зависит), тогда масса равна площади.

Comment: @VladD так с площадями я и делал, да основная проблема с триангуляцией в общем случае

Comment: @VladD т.е. мне бы 1 пункт на подпункты разбить было бы круто

Comment: @vzlomvk: Это отдельная задача, задайте её отдельным вопросом. Для вас по сути может быть проще допустить отрицательные веса и отрицательные треугольники, может быть проще. Например, для случая многоугольника с одним «входящим» углом его можно представить как выпуклый многоугольник + «отрицательный» входящий треугольник.

Comment: @VladD нашел алгоритм, но он мне не совсем понятен:
Выбирается крайняя левая вершина и между двумя ее смежными сторонами проводится диагональ. При этом могут иметь место следующие два случая:
диагональ является хордой;
диагональ — не хорда, так как внутрь треугольника попадает вершина полигона (в общем случае их может быть несколько).

Comment: @VladD Из всех вершин внутри треугольника вершина d наиболее удалена от стороны ас. Эту вершину будем называть вторгающейся. В случае, когда вторгающейся вершины нет, то полученный треугольник заносят в сетку треугольников, и алгоритм рекурсивно обрабатывает оставшийся полигон до тех пор, пока он не выродится в треугольник. При обнаружении вторгающейся вершины проводится диагональ из текущей до вторгающейся вершины. Полученные полигоны рекурсивно обрабатываются до получения треугольников.

Comment: В общем случае задачу учебной не назовёшь. И именно поэтому я хотел бы ДОПОЛНИТЬ Вашу работу - а не гадать вилами по воде, что уже сделано, а что нет.

Comment: Про вторгающуюся вершину - обязательно внесите в правку вопроса

Comment: @vzlomvk: Я ж говорю, что триангуляция невыпуклого многоугольника — отдельная задача. Давайте не будеми обсуждать её в комментариях.

Comment: @VladD а где тогда?

Comment: @vzlomvk http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/472255/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80-%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0/472262?noredirect=1#comment530492_472262

Comment: @VladD http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/472287/Триангуляция-треугольника