# Триангуляция полигона

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Алгоритм триангуляции полигона в общем случае: полигон может быть как выпуклым, так и не выпуклым.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Окей, стандартный алгоритм таков:

Разбиваем рекурсивно. Для количества вершин 3 проблем нету.

Пусть количество вершин больше трёх. Если нету «входящих» вершин, режем диагоналями из любой вершины на треугольники.

Остался случай, когда есть «входящая» вершина. Рассматриваем все диагонали, исходящие из этой вершины. Одна из них будет лежать строго внутри многоугольника*, режем ей многоугольник на две части. У каждой из частей количество вершин меньше, применяем к ним алгоритм рекурсивно.

---

*Доказательство. Пусть есть входящая вершина *X*, и из *X* отходят стороны *XY* и *XZ*. Проведём луч из *X*, идущий вдоль *XY*, и будем вращать его внутри многоугольника пока он не пойдёт по *XZ*. Поскольку он заметёт угол больше 180 градусов, он при этом не может всё время смотреть на одну и ту же сторону. Следовательно, в какой-то момент он смотрел на вершину, что и требовалось доказать.

---

Дополнение: как проверить, вершина входящая или нет? Подойдёт следующий трюк. Для последовательности вершин *A*, *B*, *C* рассмотрим [псевдоскаларное произведение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) `[AB × BC] = (x_B - x_A) * (y_C - y_B) - (y_B - y_A) * (x_C - x_B)`. Это число равно удвоенной площади тр-ка *ABC* со знаком. Знак плюс соответствует повороту от *AB* к *AC* против часовой стрелки, и минус — по. (Или наоборот, не уверен на 100%. Но это не важно.)

Таким образом, если при обходе все смены направлений идут по часовой стрелке, а одна против — вы нашли входящую вершину.

Comment: Реализовать будет не просто, но суть ясна. Спасибо!

Comment: @vzlomvk: Дописал доказательство.

Comment: как появится возможность, отмечу как "ответ"

Comment: @vzlomvk: Дополнил ответ ещё.

Comment: можно же взять 3 последовательно идущие точки и проверить лежит ли 2 левее/правее или выше/ниже от геометрического центра

Comment: @vzlomvk: Хм. А если одна правее, а другая нет? Например, идут по диагонали?